# Add/Remove both duplicate results from SQL query based on flag

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table that includes data where I want to grab all rows with a flag of zero as well as rows with a positive flag of my choosing, then I would like it to remove all data from the query that contains the same data, but has a negative flag value.  Currently I am handling all of this in my front end by grabbing all my 0 and positive flag values, then grabbing all my negative values and removing them from my first result set all rows with flag >= 0 that match the negative flag rows.

These things are always a bit to describe in words, so here is an example with my data set looking something similar to the following:

```
flag    name    loc
0       Fred    USA
-1      Fred    USA
1       Fred    CANADA
0       Ryan    CANADA
0       Steph   SPAIN
-1      Steph   SPAIN
1       Steph   CANADA
-2      Steph   CANADA
2       Steph   RUSSIA
```

If I wanted all data with a flag of 1, I would expect to return the following

```
flag    name    loc
1       Fred    CANADA
0       Ryan    CANADA
1       Steph   CANADA
```

If flag was just 2, I would want

```
flag    name    loc
0       Fred    USA
0       Ryan    CANADA
2       Steph   RUSSIA
```

And finally if flag was 1 OR 2, I would want

```
flag    name    loc
1       Fred    CANADA
0       Ryan    CANADA
2       Steph   RUSSIA
```

Note that although the flag appears to be sequential in this example, it can not be assumed that a higher flagged item is the final flagged row to be chosen.  Also, this is a subquery for a larger query that gathers information based on this query.  The main query can contain any number of flags.

Is this operation doable in a query, or should I continue doing the heavy lifting in the front-end?

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de297/1

Thanks

Comment: Because I copied Fred's data and forgot to modify it!  I fixed my table, thanks.  Also modified the sentence you quoted as it was not technically correct as I am removing all with a flag >= 0 that match negative rows.

Answer (score 0):

This satisfies your first two requirements but I'm not sure what if

> if flag was 1 OR 2, I would want

means

```
DECLARE @YourInt INT = 2     

SELECT    flag,
          name,
          loc
INTO      #YourInts
FROM      table1
WHERE     flag = @YourInt

SELECT   flag,
         name,
         loc
FROM     #YourInts
UNION ALL
SELECT   flag,
         name,
         loc
FROM     table1
WHERE    flag = 0 AND
         name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM #YourInts WHERE flag = @YourInt)
```

Comment: I think this is where it gets even more tricky and I should have explained a bit more.  This is a subquery for a larger query that, for this example, would do something like "grab all the information I have for the locations given by this query WHERE flag is equal to 1 OR 2 (...OR 3 OR 4...)" where my WHERE clause could include any any N number of flags.  I will update my original question with this information when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is prioritization with filtering:

```
select *
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by flag desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
      where flag in (0, 1)
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `where` condition has the list of acceptable flag values.  It seems you always want `0` in that list.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de297/26) is a db<>fiddle.